# WebView tries to submit form when only one input is available on page

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to load an HTML page with a form that has **only one number input field**. The desired behavior is:

When the user enters some data in this field and clicks on *forward button* from the Android's keyboard, a function is executed and a value appears, without taking him to another page.

The problem is that when the user clicks forward, the app crashes due to a [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html). After searching a bit, I saw that this error is related to [this bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3208).

One of the solutions shown in ([2](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3208)) was *add an extra invisible form field*, but does anyone know another solution? Because I think that changing all HTML forms will be something much more time consuming than trying a solution via Android.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if avoiding clicking forward would help, but here is a way you can submit to the form without the user typing in the form directly, if you have them enter the number into an edittext, save its value and then use something like this. You can set the webview visibility to invisible if you want to start and then make it visible after it submits. You can find out the IDs of the elements in the form by right clicking and hitting Inspect.

```
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.form_url));
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                String fieldID;
                String submitButtonID;
                int numberTypedInByUser

                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                        "document.getElementById('"+fieldID+"').value = '"+numberTypedInByUser+"';" +
                        "var z = document.getElementById('"+submitButtonID+"').click(); };");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I really need is to keep the user in the same page, without taking him to another page, even if he clicks on the form submission via android keyboard. Also, the entire form is built in HTML, with no Android Views involved